# egrep: empty (sub)expression : Unexpected behaviour for bash Loop on Mac

Tags: terminal, bash, bug

I have the filling simplified script on Mac OS X 10.12 :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "=> BASH_VERSION = $BASH_VERSION"
function testForLoopMac {
local file
for file
do
    echo File=$file
done | egrep "$file"
}

function testForLoopMacBis {
local file
for file
do
    echo File=$file
done | egrep "$file|OK"
}

testForLoopMac $@

testForLoopMacBis $@
```

But the result when I run is :

```
$ testForLoopMac.sh example.pdf 
=> BASH_VERSION = 3.2.57(1)-release
File=example.pdf
egrep: empty (sub)expression
```

On Debian/Ubuntu Linux, the result is :

```
$ testForLoopMac.sh example.md 
=> BASH_VERSION = 4.3.30(1)-release
File=example.md
File=example.md
```

Edit : With bash4 on Mac OSX 10.12 :

I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash4` and the result is the same :

```
$ testForLoopMac.sh example.md 
=> BASH_VERSION = 4.4.12(1)-release
File=example.md
egrep: empty (sub)expression
```

Edit: Thanks to you guys I understand the behavior difference on Linux or BSD `egrep` is because that at the time of the `egrep` execution the variable can be empty.

I'm going the use therefore, the following regExp :

`egrep "File=|OK"`

Thanks again :)

Comment: Can you add the `BASH_VERSION` both from macOS and from Linux?

Comment: I think the script is too simplified to show your real intent. Are the arguments to the script supposed to be regular expressions?

Comment: @patrix I update the Question with the bash version information because comments only use mini-Markdown formatting which is a pain in the @~~

Comment: For what it's worth editing the question to include such information is the preferred thing to do rather than adding it in the comments since comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @0942v8653 the script is ideal to show how execution on macOS and Linux differ. Which is all the question is about :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell expands the subexpression `$file` on the right hand side of the pipe before the variable has any value. So in both functions `egrep` is actually called with the empty string in place of `$file`. The first function doesn't throw an error because an empty pattern is a valid parameter for `egrep` both on macOS and on Linux. In the second fucntion the difference comes into play because the empty subexpression causes `BSD egrep` (the one used on macOS) to throw an error.

Example:

```
echo foo | egrep "|foo"
egrep: empty (sub)expression
```

as another example with `$file` having no value

```
echo foo | egrep "$file|foo"
egrep: empty (sub)expression
```

So, as a workaround in your function use:

```
egrep -e "$file" -e 'OK'
```

I have no idea why you are using `egrep` when you are looking for fixed strings.

Comment: The expansion is done by `bash` not by `egrep`, so I struggle a bit to understand your first sentence.

Comment: @patrix Yep, you're right. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder why it works on Linux though

Comment: @patrix  It's the difference between `BSD grep` and `GNU grep`. `GNU grep` doesn't complain about empty subexpressions for one thing.

Comment: @patrix Maybe, on linux, the variable is not distroyed when the loop is finished.

Comment: @SebMa The variable isn't "destroyed" on either system (replace `| egrep` by `; echo` to check). The way pipes work the second command (`egrep`) needs to be started *before* the loop terminates. So both functions don't work as you may think they to, in the first function `egrep` is executed with an empty pattern (because `file` is empty at the moment of execution), in the second the difference between BSD and GNU grep (as explained above) comes into play.

Comment: @fd0. I'm using `egrep` to filter the output of `ffprobe` to simplify it a little.

Comment: @patrix Thanks for your explanation.

I'm going the use therefore, the following regExp : `egrep "File=|OK"`

Comment: @SebMa Just avoid using any variables in the right hand side of a pipe which get set/changed in the left hand side